# What are the differences between mod-wsgi and libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3?

Tags: drivers, package-management, apache2, virtualhost, django

I am learning about virtual hosting. I have a Django project and need WSGI module. Reading multiple tutorials, I see that people install different packages of mod-wsgi, for example mod-wsgi and libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3. What are differences among them?

Where should I read to know the differences of these similar packages? How do I choose one over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly looked and it seems that package **mod-wsgi** is not an Ubuntu package. If you mention difference between **libapache2-mod-wsgi** and **libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3**, it only because the first use python 2 while the second one use python 3, so the version you have to install depends of the project language version.

Comment: "not an Ubuntu package" What does it mean? What kind of the package is this?

Comment: The mod-wsgi (https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) is the common project name to identify the Apache module, but Ubuntu renamed it to libapache2-mod-wsgi for more clarification. Both identify the same software.

Comment: I came here for what would be equivalent of libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 for python2 in ubuntu and the answer i needed.